# Is there something like get DaysInMonth for in elixir?

Tags: datetime, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have searched on Ecto.DateTime, but unfortunately didn't find anything useful. Is there a way to get last day of the month?

I have a query where I load orders from psql, from yesterday (31 July) to today (1 Aug), with today I just use 1, but for the yesterday it can be 31, 30, 29 or 28. Is there a way to know how many days are in the previous month?

Thanks in advance, and any advise appreciated!

Comment: So your ultimate goal is to find the date of yesterday?

Comment: In general, it's often wise to check the Erlang OTP docs for these sorts of questions too.  There's a lot of good stuff already built into that library that Elixir doesn't bother to duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [`:calendar.last_day_of_the_month/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#last_day_of_the_month-2) which accepts a year and month as arguments.

```
iex(1)> :calendar.last_day_of_the_month(2000, 2)
29
iex(2)> :calendar.last_day_of_the_month(2001, 2)
28
```

> **last_day_of_the_month(Year, Month) -> LastDay**
>
> Types:
>
> ```
> Year = year()
> Month = month()
> LastDay = ldom()
> ```
>
> Computes the number of days in a month.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I will try now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `days_in_month/2` function in the `Calendar.ISO` implementation in Elixir:

```
Calendar.ISO.days_in_month(year, month)
```

For example, `Calendar.ISO.days_in_month(2019, 7)` will return `31`.

You can find more information in the docs here: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Calendar.ISO.html#days_in_month/2